# vba code for filtering on multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook having multiple sheets and same number of columns in each sheet. Everyday new sheet is added in workbook.

Can filtered data on the first sheet be transferred to succeeding sheets by running vba code ?

Regards

Comment: Yes, but SO isn't a code writing service.  If you have some code that you have tried and it isn't working, then post it and tell us where it's throwing an error, plus what the error is and we'll try to help.

Comment: Do a web search on your title, this a quite a popular subject

Comment: Thank you, Mark and Daves. On web I got one code but it showing error " Application-defined or object defined error". Please help, how I post code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Access the filters of the first sheet and the corresponding filtered range with

```
    Dim rng As Range
    With Sheets(1)     
      .AutoFilter
    Set rng = .AutoFilter.Range
    End With
```

All Information on filters is stored in the filters collection of the AutoFilter object

```
Dim filters As Filters 
Set filters = Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Filters
```

Every item in this collection represents one column in the filtered range. The following Statement would get you criteria1 of the first column:

```
filters.Item(1).Criteria1
```

You can use the obtained Information on the other Sheets you want to transfer them to. Do this via the AutoFilter method of the Range Object ([Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb242013(v=office.12).aspx))

If the columns are identical as you say you can get the target range easily by using the address property:

```
Sheets(n).Range(rng.address).AutoFilter arguments_here
```

Comment: @KISHORBHOIR Can you please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem? Thank you